# lightning-datatable with custom cell and component mutates Id field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Consider the [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/x8d2rafOZ/1/edit) and screenshot below.
[image: datatable screenshot with random integers appended to id]

Notice -11 and -14 added to the Id. I believe it somehow relates to `key` fields. Unsure how to correctly specify key field in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

`id` (lowercase) is an attribute that uniquely identifies an element within the DOM. This uniqueness is necessary for proper operation of LWC. What's happening is that you're assigning the value to this, so it gets modified during rendering. To fix this, use a different attribute name.

Here's a minimal fix to your code:

## customCell.html

```
<template>
    <c-custom-table-component
            name={typeAttributes.Name}
            value={typeAttributes.Id}>
    </c-custom-table-component>
</template>
```

## customTableComponent.html

```
<template>
    {value}
</template>
```

## customTableComponent.js

```
import {LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';

export default class CustomTableComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api name
    @api value
}
```

Comment: Yep workaround I've used yday was `recordId` param. Still seems like a bug in lwc rather than my fault!

Comment: @dzh No, it's intentional. You can't use `id` on a component because the DOM needs it.

Comment: Shouldn't compile then?